# GRUB Multiboot header not found

Tags: linker, 32-bit, osdev, grub, multiboot

After reading this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539464/grub-2-not-detecting-multiboot-header-in-kernel) and it's primary answer, I ran readelf on my kernel, and noticed my .text section was at 0x00101000 and not 0x00100000. I also noticed a section above that read .not.gnu.build-i that was in the place the .text section is supposed to be. Is there a way I could make my .text section be in the correct place? I have already used `align 4` to set it to 1M.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `LD` (or *LD* via *GCC*) is automatically placing a notes section (if one was generated) in the first 4k. If linking the final kernel with *GCC* pass it the `-Wl,--build-id=none` option. If you are using *LD* directly to link the final binary then you can pass it `--build-id=none` .

If writing a multiboot *ELF* object the existence of this extra section can force the mulitboot header beyond the 8k position in the file. This is accounting for the fact that *ELF* headers usually take a minimum of the first 4k of the file. Add in the 4k for `.note.gnu.build-id` and `.multiboot` section is now beyond 8k mark of the physical file. This will cause a multiboot loader like GRUB to think your *ELF* executable doesn't have a multiboot header since it only looks through the first 8k of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your linker script (given that it is the same as in the other question) is the problem: By telling it to 4k-align the sections and putting `multiboot` in a separate section, you allocate 4k for it, so `.text` starts at an offset of 1M + 4k, which causes your problem. Change it to the following:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;

    .text ALIGN(4K) :
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }

[snip]
```